# Matlab combine cells and strings into a cell

Tags: matlab

I have multiple files whose data are dispersed throughout the file and when I textscan them into Matlab, I get a cell of cells or strings.  For example,

```
data_in = {'aaaa';'bbbb';{'cccc','dddd','eeee','ffff'};'gggg';{'hhhh','iiii'};'jjjj'}
```

and so on.  In other words;

```
data_in = {1x1 str;1x1 str;1x4 cell;1x1 str;1x2 cell;1x1 str}
```

and this can be any combination depending on a data file.  My question is how to combine them into 1xn cell?  I tried data_in = data_in(:) or data_in{:}, but neither worked.  What I want to have is:

```
data_in = {'aaaa','bbbb','cccc','dddd','eeee','ffff','gggg','hhhh','iiii','jjjj'}
```

Comment: Just note: In the question marked as duplicate of, for you the solution is not the accepted one but the another: `data_in = [data_in{:}];`

Comment: @DVarga it worked beautifully.  Why then, though, {:} alone didn't work?